# JavaScript change the border from middle to left and right，use transition prototype？

Tags: javascript, css

I don’t want use or i don't know how to use 'the CSS:after prototype' by javascript .
Now, I change it is by add height not width,and when i remove the class prototype, reback is a short time,no transtion.
What can i do for it?
this is my codepen  [link](https://codepen.io/xuedaobian/pen/xxGeqmE)

```html
<div class="block">
    <div id="top">my block/div>
    <div>
      <button id="btn">submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.block {
      height: 200px;
      width: 250px;
      margin:150px auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #top {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      height: 30px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-bottom: 3px solid;
      transition: 1s all cubic-bezier(.46, 1, .23, 1.52);
    }
    .addtop {
      border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
      color: blue;
    }
```

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click',() => {
      let topBlock = document.getElementById('top');
      if(topBlock.classList.length > 0) {
        topBlock.classList = [];
      } else {
        topBlock.classList.add('addtop');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('top');
  if(topBlock.classList.length > 0) {
    topBlock.classList.remove('addtop');
  } else {
    topBlock.classList.add('addtop');
  }
});
```

Also add to .top class:

```
  border-bottom: 0px solid blue;
```